# Day of the Tentacle Remastered iOS Lavergne Bug

Tags: ios, day-of-the-tentacle-remastered

So I've been playing DoTT Remastered and I've managed to retrieve the roller skates without collecting the extension cord at the same time and enter the mummy into the contest.

The problem is now that the contest has finished the mummy is back in the room wearing the roller skates and I can no longer collect the extension cord in order to fire up her chron-o-jon!

Is there an alternative to extending the power plug or have I found a bug?

I've quadruple-checked that no other players have the extension cord or that I used it on something else.

I'm 100% certain I never collected it.

Unfortunately I only have the one save game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out if you hover in the classic mode you can still get the extension cord if you're really smooth and careful with the mouse movements. This works even though the Mummy is completely covering the extension cord.

[image]